# How to Make cakephp mail readonly

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I am Using cakephp 2.10.
I am sending mails using templates . But when user tries to forward the mail they can edit the text and forward to any other.My Query is is it possible to make it un editable?
I googled and get solution as 'convert it to image before send' but that conversion is giving image output which i cant use to send mail. and the output is also different from my content.
What alternative options i have?
Please assist
Thank you in advance.

Comment: May I ask why you can't send images as mail?

Comment: If I don't like people changing the text of a received email I would go with an attached PDF. But remember that there is no such a thing as 'read only' when talking about the web. You can still edit an image or a PDF even a protected one